# String Manipulations in Drupal

Tags: 7

I've been retrieving information from  a database for display.

```
function myid_user_page_form(){   
    $query = db_select('student', 't1',array('target' => 'import'));
    $result = $query->fields('t1', array('firstname','middlename'));

    foreach ($result as $record) {
        $info['firstname'] = $record->firstname; 
        $info['middlename'] = $record->middlename; 
    }
}
```

In my case, all data stored in my database is all uppercase. For example:

```
$info['firstname'] = "ALYSSA"
$info['middlename'] = "ENGANIO"
```

I want to make "ALYSSA" to "Alyssa" and make "ENGANIO" to "E.". How will I do that in Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal can help you doing this by its unicode functions.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21unicode.inc/7

"ALYSSA" to "Alyssa" would be

```
<?php
  $name = drupal_ucfirst(drupal_strtolower($name));
?>
```

And "ENGANIO" to "E." would be:

```
<?php
  $name = drupal_strtoupper(drupal_substr($name, 0, 1)) . '.';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

not a Drupal question, but here you go..

```
<?php
// proudly found elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518021/1158887
function mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding)
{
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string, $encoding);
    $firstChar = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $encoding);
    $then = mb_substr($string, 1, $strlen - 1, $encoding);
    return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
}

function myid_user_page_form(){   
    $query = db_select('student', 't1',array('target' => 'import'));
    $result = $query->fields('t1', array('firstname','middlename'));

    foreach ($result as $record) {
        $info['firstname'] = mb_ucfirst(mb_strtolower($record->firstname, 'UTF-8'));
        $info['middlename'] = mb_substr(mb_ucfirst($record->middlename, 'UTF-8'), 0, 1) . '.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Drupal does have specific string functions that should be used to manipulate strings. The question as posted isn't Drupal-specific enough, since the OP is just asking how to alter two strings, and this could be done even with plain PHP functions.